# Connection String generated by VS doesn't work, and any variation of it

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-core

I'm deploying a web application using IIS and ASP.NET CORE.
I setup a "appsetting.json" file that include a connection string to sql server.
So far, any variation I've tried didn't work.
The strange thing about it, is that it works perfectly on a my local machine, but when I deploy it and send an HTTPPost, log file says there's an error using connection to database on server.

Well, I tried all variations I could think of.
Current connection string generated by Visual Studio is :

> Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Swap;Integrated
>   Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;
>   TrustServerCertificate=False;
>   ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

I've tried changing the "Integrated Security" to False.
I've tried to replace it with User ID and password (of "sa" user).
I've tried adding a "Initial Catalog" property and set it to my database.

I'm preety sure the startup of the app is fine, because when I try to send a GET request to the main page, everything seems fine.
When I send a POST request and asks the DBcontext to Add and SaveChanges, it shows this error :

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
>   An error occurred using the connection to database 'Swap' on server
>   '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.

This is the function that I tried to send a HTTPPost request to:

```
byte[] j = new byte[(int)Request.ContentLength];
Request.Body.Read(j, 0, (int)Request.ContentLength);
string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(j);
TokenSet tokenSet = new TokenSet {Token = str };
sqlTokensetData.Add<TokenSet>(tokenSet);
sqlTokensetData.SaveChanges();
HttpClient notificationSender = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=" 
<somekey>);

request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sender", "id=<id>");
Message pushNotification = new Message(new string[] { str }, "Success!" 
<somestring>);

request.Content = new 
StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pushNotification)
,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

HttpResponseMessage output = await notificationSender.SendAsync(request);
```

Log file error:
https://anotepad.com/notes/9a8jxa

I hope that the "str" string will be inserted to the database.
Thank you.

Comment: You're using the "localdb" flavor of SQL Server Express that spins up a user process to host your databases on demand.  For a server applciation, install the "service" flavor of SQL Server Express Edition and use that instead. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express

Comment: _“I'm pretty sure the startup of the app is fine, because when I try to send a GET request to the main page, everything seems fine.”_ – Unless you are actually retrieving some data from the database on that main page, that has nothing to do with whether your database connection works.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft so Localdb wont work with my server application?

Comment: Basically, yes.  SQL Server Express LocalDB is intended for desktop applications, where the SQL Server Express service is intended for server applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Basicly, Thanks to the comments above I've managed to solve it.
What you need to do if you come by the same error:
1.Download SQL Server Express - 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express as said above.
and configure the SQL Server however you see fit.
2.Configure sa user, set password and enable it.
3. If SQL Authentication doesn't work, then in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio -> Right-click the server -> Properties -> Server Authentication -> Change to SQL Server and Windows Authentication
4. Change connection string to :

> Data Source=;Initial Catalog=User ID=sa;
>   Password=;
>   Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;
>   ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

It worked for me.